# Subsequently change an indicator variable for all occurrences/re-occurrences of an ID

Tags: r, database

I aim to change an indicator variable for all occurrences/re-occurrences of an ID

Dataframe

```
ID    Value    Indicator
1       10        1
2       3         1 
3       5         0 
1       8         0
4       7         0
2       5         0
```

What I need now (that reoccurring IDs also equal 1 in the indicator column)

```
ID    Value    Indicator
1       10        1
2       3         1 
3       5         0 
1       8         1
4       7         0
2       5         1
```

Is there a way to base that on the ID column?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. You mean "at a later stage" or (as your code suggests) in the other data frame?

Comment: I meant more like when the same ID appears again (e.g. ID 1 and 2 appear again)

Comment: ID = 4 is only present in your dataframe once. Question is very confusing. Does Dataframe2 always have the indicator = 1 at least once for each ID? If that was the case you wouldn't need Dataframe1 at all? Or are you trying to have indicator = 1 for all occurrences of an ID in Dataframe2 that is present in Dataframe1?

Comment: Sorry meant ID 2 and yeah the latter. I try to have the indicator to show 1 for reoccurring IDs!

Comment: Still confused about exactly what you need. I will answer with two options and then maybe tell me which is preferred then edit the post to make it obvious why you needed that solution?

Comment: Made an edit to potentially make it clear and less complicated...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each ID in Dataframe2 has at least 1 Indicator = 1 (as the code above suggests) and the aim is to ensure all occurrences of this ID have Indicator = 1:

```
Dataframe2 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Indicator = case_when(any(Indicator==1) ~ 1 ,
                               T ~ 0))
```

Assuming that all occurences of an ID in Dataframe2  that appear in Dataframe1 should have Indicator = 1 (and some ID in Dataframe2 that appear in Dataframe1 do not already have at least 1 Indicator = 1):

```
Dataframe1$Value <- NULL
Dataframe2$Indicator <- NULL

Dataframe2 <- left_join(Dataframe2, Dataframe1, by = "ID")
```

Comment: From your edit removing Dataframe1 I assume the first answer is what you are looking for?

Comment: I assumed so as well but it has been processing that code for 10 mins and I do not think that is actually making any progress there.

Comment: How big is your Dataframe2?

Comment: 290k observations